# Detect Source Of HTML5 Video Pause/Play On Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-javascript-api

On mobile phones, if an HTML5 video is playing and the screen is turned off, the video is automatically paused.

How can I detect if the pause/play action was triggered explicitly by the user (by pressing play/pause) or by the system (due to the screen turning off, etc.?)

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery:

```
$('.yourclassforvideo').on('pause', function() {
    // Do your code
});
```

I'm not sure if it will be triggered once the screen is locked. Try it out and see what happens :P

Comment: Unfortunately it is with no indication of who called it as far as I can tell.